# What does build status in github mean on js repos

Tags: javascript, build, github

I constantly see github js repos with build status notifications ([like here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)). It would make sense if it was a compiled project like `java` or `c++` but it's javascript, worse thing that can happen is a thrown exception.

What does build status mean in an interpreted language context?

Comment: It could simply mean that the tests are all passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript can be used on the server (*nodejs*) or browser. Either way, in general terms, a build status indicates whether your software (javascript in this case) has passed the build tests that are required in order for your software to work as expected.

TravisCI is the software that deals with running the tests that you the Developer set up in advance: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/getting-started/. TravisCI is integrated into GitHub for free... it is a free service.

The way it works is that you setup a configuration file named `.travis.yml` in your repo's root directory, and TravisCI will "build" your project - meaning it will run the tests that you've setup in advance... such as Unit Tests, checking that your code works with the latest NodeJS version, jQuery version, checking dependencies, and other tasks that are important to your project.

These tests/checks can and will run on every new push to your repo, making sure that the new changes to your code haven't broken your project's functionality. This kind of automated testing can be very helpful when more than one developer writes code for a project. Think of TravisCI as a project cop that explicitly fails your project when your code hasn't passed the required tests, and doesn't have the dependencies it needs. Although there could be other reasons as well.

It seems (to me at least) that TravisCI is used in larger projects in the JS community, but that doesn't mean that it couldn't be used for smaller ones either. Personally I've never used this service - I'm just aware of it and keeping my eyes open in case I ever need it. Hope this clarifies it a little for you.

**UPDATE:**
Sure, this is a test too. It tests the project with the two provided NodeJS versions (0.8 & 0.6).

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.8
  - 0.6
```

Directly quoted form the TravisCI docs:

> "Node.js projects specify releases they need to be tested against
>   using node_js key".

You can find specific NodeJS details here: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/

And general configuration details are here: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#.travis.yml-file%3A-what-it-is-and-how-it-is-used

If the developers wanted, they could have added more tests or things to happen that would affect the build status. There are many examples here: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/.

For example one could run Shell scripts that perhaps run your JS file(s) through JSLint, JSHint, Google Closure Compiler, or whatever else. You can also add configuration properties to this `.travis.yml` file that will send you an email on every build, or connect to one of their DBs - mysql, mongodb, etc.

I think a good way to learn more about it is to read the docs. Perhaps Google can find other people's writings on the subject too. The best way to learn though is to roll up your sleeves up high and give it a try.

I'll be honest though, half of these things are over my head as well, and I've never used it for any of my small-ass projects. Hope it makes more sense now.

**UPDATE 2:**

> Doesn't a project need tests in order for it to be tested?

Yes it does, and that's the whole point. If you follow their directions in the docs and create an account, I'm sure you will find answers to all of your questions.

When signing up with TravisCI, a VM will be available and connect/sync with your github repo. If in your `.yml` file you chose NodeJS as the language, then the VM will have NodeJS installed.

If you added a `script:` key with a value of a `shell script (.sh)`, then this script will execute. If you know how to develop in shell, then you can do all sort of tests and amazing things. As I said, you could run you file through a Linter, validator, or you can run some other JS files in a headless Browser (PhantomJS). The JS files that run in phantom can be the unit-tests themselves. Here is how it's done: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/

More on unit-testing: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Default-Test-Script - Just read the section about using `Using Vows`.

If you want to understand exactly how TravisCI does all these things, then learning Ruby will be a great first step.

Comment: But all there is in [**this repos**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) [**travis.yml**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/.travis.yml) file contains just `language: node_js` and some versions, nowhere in that file or in the project is there any mention of tests

Comment: Doesn't a project need tests in order for it to be tested?

Answer (score 0):

Any project can have a build phase, even if that just means you're compressing the JavaScript to a minified version or build the documentation or similar such tasks. Most of the time for "buildless" projects it means a suite of tests is run against the latest version automatically.

Comment: What do you mean, I don't see any build step in [**this project**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: Please read my answer again. Also, click on the build status badge and read through the log of a build. In this case it's installing all dependencies needed through `npm` and runs a series of tests. It basically tests the whole thing from zero to completed tests automatically, which is not something you usually do manually very often during development. Simulating a complete checkout and dependency installation cycle every once in a while helps to ensure it actually works, since you usually won't notice problems with such things during regular development.